# Cargo maven plugin - cannot deploy local war - "Artifact is not a dependency of the project"

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-cargo, cargo-maven2-plugin

I would like to use cargo maven plugin (cargo-maven2-plugin) for this scenario:

- I have selenium test framework (ProjectT), containing core, page objects and some steps used for UI testing of ProjectA. For this framework exists some integration tests (selenium smoke tests) to verify its validity.
- The goal is to run local embedded jetty server via cargo, deploy war (from local repo) with ProjectA into it and then run integration tests from ProjectT against this running ProjectA

But I am getting trouble to deploy ProjectA war using cargo.

There is plugin configuration inside my ProjectT pom:

```
[...]

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mefi</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>

    [...]

<dependencies>

[...]

<plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
       <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.17</version>
       <configuration>
          <!-- Container definition -->
          <container>
             <containerId>jetty7x</containerId>
             <type>embedded</type>
             <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.mefi</groupId>
                   <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
                   <type>war</type>
                </dependency>
             </dependencies>
          </container>
          <configuration>
             <properties>
                <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
             </properties>
          </configuration>
          <deployables>
             <deployable>
                <groupId>com.mefi</groupId>
                <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
             </deployable>
          </deployables>
       </configuration>
       <!-- Setting for container starting/stoping during phases. -->
       <executions>
          <execution>
             <id>start-server</id>
             <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
             <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
             </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
             <id>stop-server</id>
             <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
             <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
             </goals>
          </execution>
       </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

run from ProjectT:

`mvn org.codehaus.cargo: cargo-maven2-plugin:run -Dcargo.servlet.port=9000`

ERROR message:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.17:run  (default-cli) on project airtest-selenium: Artifact [com.mefi:project-a:war] is not a dependency of the project. -> [Help 1]`

artifact with builded war exists in my local repo (was previously built). I also tried add it as a dependency

Please, could you help me what I am missing? Why is not a dependecy?

Comment: What about `mvn clean verify`

Comment: @khmarbaise: Hello, this gives me same error message about artifact is not a dependency of the project

Comment: Assuming you have a multi module build? If yes can you add the structure you have created and from where you are calling Maven...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your attention, I don`t know why but it started to works. I cant found what modificatin caused it, or if there were troubles with maven cache etc, but it works now. I am not able to reproduce it again. So this question does not make sense anymore. Thanks again.

Comment: @mefi I am struck at the same point as you were with Cargo throwing the same error. Can you please let me know how you've resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your artifact ID was wrong because of parent-child hierarchy.

If your parent is: `com.mefi -> project-root`

Your deployable should be `com.mefi -> project-a`

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the type of the deployer so above deployable put this

```
<deployer>
<type>war</type>
</deployer>
<deployables>
<deployable>
```